# Where is the correct place to break this simple 'while' loop?

Tags: c#

Where is the correct place to break this while loop?

Simple console number guessing game. User has 3 tries to guess a randomly generated number.

My problem is that on the third try, if the guess is incorrect, the Console prints "Try again - Game Over" instead of just "Game over". If the 3rd guess is incorrect, how and where is the correct place to exit the loop and say "Game over"?

```
using System;

namespace asdf2
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int number = r.Next(1, 6);
            int nOfGuesses = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("You have 3 tries to guess my number");

            while (nOfGuesses < 3)
            {
                string guess = Console.ReadLine();
                int guessedNumber = Convert.ToInt16(guess);

                if (guessedNumber != number)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Try again");
                    nOfGuesses++;
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("You got it!");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Game over");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put a 'if (guessedNumber<2)` before your Writline: Try Again

Comment: @Hogler - You mean 'if (nOfGusses<2)' before WriteLine. 

Yup. That fixed it. Thanks!!

Comment: `if (nOfGuesses>=2) break;` at the same place would have the same effect. Actually you need to break after "got it" also. Right now you continue after "got it" until three numbers are entered.

Answer (score 3):

The complication here is that a `while` loop evaluates the condition **before** executing the loop's body. Instead, you could use a `do while` loop that executes the body and then evaluates the condition. Also, note that regardless of the type of loop you use, you should break out of it once the user guessed correctly:

```
do
{
    string guess = Console.ReadLine();
    int guessedNumber = Convert.ToInt16(guess);

    if (guessedNumber != number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Try again");
        nOfGuesses++;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You got it!");
        break;
    }
} while (nOfGuesses < 3);
```

Comment: This changes actually nothing, except it omits the first test.

Answer (score 1):

Not that different than the other answers, but it *might* make sense just to remove the `break` entirely. (Insert code/religious war here.)

```
while(++nOfguesses <= 3 && number != guessedNumber)
{
    var guess = Console.ReadLine();
    var guessedNumber = Convert.ToInt16(guess);
    if (number != guessedNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Try again.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You got it!");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Game over.");
```